# Remap LeftAlt + hjkl to arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb

I'm trying to remap LeftAlt + hjkl to my arrow keys using an XKB layout.

Here's my current config (non-functional):

```
    key <AC06> {        [         h, H, Left            ]       };
    key <AC07> {        [         j, J, Down            ]       };
    key <AC08> {        [         k, K, Up              ]       };
    key <AC09> {        [         l, L, Right           ]       };
    key <LALT> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
```

The issue seems to be comming from the LALT -> ISO_Level3_Shift remap, because the ISO_Level3_Shift + hjkl mapping works fine if I use CAPS instead of LALT.

How can I make this work with LeftAlt?